# QGIS 2.2 saving layer as CSV with GEOMETRY=AS_WKT not working

Tags: qgis, csv, well-known-text

Just upgraded to QGIS 2.2 and it looks like saving a layer as CSV doesn't support GEOMETRY=AS_WKT anymore. The new Layer Options portion of the save dialog is cool but it looks like GEOMETRY and LINEFORMAT for CSV have some swapped options (CRLF and AS_WKT are in opposite option lists). I tried custom layer options:

```
GEOMETRY=AS_WKT
SEPARATOR=SEMICOLON
LINEFORMAT=CRLF
```

Those worked under QGIS 2.0 but don't appear to work with QGIS 2.2.

Comment: Assuming this is an actual regression, the QGIS issue tracker seems like a better place for this: http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues

Comment: Yes, it looks like it's already been reported here: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9597

Comment: is there any solution to this?