# Save as .csv with coordinates in both QGIS 2.2 and PyqGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, csv

These questions have been asked before, but since they are not answered I will try to pick up the ends here.

1) First, as stated here:

[QGIS 2.2 saving layer as CSV with GEOMETRY=AS_WKT not working](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88936/qgis-2-2-saving-layer-as-csv-with-geometry-as-wkt-not-working)

in Qgis 2.2 it is not possible to save a shapefile as .csv including the coordinates using the function _GEOMETRY=AS_WKT_. The issue

http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9597

is set to closed. Does it mean that it has been fixed? And if so, how to make it work again?

2) Second, if you want to save a shape file as .csv with coordinates through PyQgis it can be done with:

```
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61857/how-to-write-vector-layer-to-csv-file-with-geometry-by-python
```

as stated here:

[How to write vector layer to csv file with geometry by PYTHON?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61857/how-to-write-vector-layer-to-csv-file-with-geometry-by-python)

But again, this does not save the coordinates, and I can't find any solution to this either. So right now, I still have to use an old version on QGIS.

IS there any solutions to these, available at the moment?

Comment: The bug is fixed in current master, available as qgis-dev in the Osgeo4W setup, or by building from source. It will be available to all in QGIS 2.4.

Comment: Ok, good to know. So at the moment in QGIS 2.2 it is not possible to save a shape file with coordinates to .csv via python console?

Comment: Only with the mmqgis plugin.

Comment: How do you call mmqgis's Geometry export to CSV from the console? I cant find any documentation on it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use the console.

Comment: ok, thanks for the help. I will awit to use it until the 2.4 release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PYQGIS a shape file can be save as a .csv with coordinates by:

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vlayer, "xy.csv", "utf-8", None, "CSV", layerOptions ='GEOMETRY=AS_WKT')
```

This is not working in QGIS 2.2 but will work again in QGIS 2.4.

Comment: use `layerOptions =['GEOMETRY=AS_WKT']` in QGIS 2.18