# Cluster analysis using buffers and polygon features (NOT layer)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, buffer, intersect

I have a point-based vector layer, where each point represents a road accident. I am trying to write a function that:

1. Loops through my accident layer
2. creates a buffer, of a given radius, around each point/accident
3. counts the number of accidents, from the accident layer, within each buffer
4. if the number of accidents within (i.e. that intersect) the buffer is above a given threshold, then add this buffer as a polygon to a separate, pre-defined layer

What I have so far:

```
def get_clusters(layer, out_layer, buff_size, acc_threshold):

    segs = 100   #buffer segments

    source_layer = core.QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(layer)[0]
    # get CRS
    CRS = source_layer.crs().authid()
    # make the output layer
    cluster_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs={0}".format(CRS),out_layer,"memory")

    # set up loop and empty list for areas of interest
    my_clusters = []
    for accident_feature in source_layer.getFeatures():
        acc_buffer = accident_feature.geometry().buffer(buff_size,segs)

        # At this point I'm not sure how to proceed. I think I need to use something like

        request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterRect(acc_buffer.geometry().boundingBox())
        areas_of_interest = source_layer.getFeatures(request)

        for area in areas_of_interest:
        ## pseudo-code - haven't got far enough to test this    
           if area.featureCount() >= acc_threshold:
              my_clusters.append(area.id())
```

but that's about as far as I can get. I need the intersection-object to be a circle (i.e. just the buffer polygon), but I can't find something like `setFilterArea` that I could pass the `acc_buffer.geometry()` in to.

I hope the above is clear, if someone could point me in the right direction I'm quite content working out the rest for myself but currently I'm a bit stuck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the most efficient way to do this. Instead of creating buffers and looking for intersections, you can do this with [scipy.spatial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.1/reference/spatial.html) library.

First get all of your points (accidents) as numpy array. From csv file it will be:

```
from scipy import loadtxt
data = loadtxt("/path/to/file.csv", delimiter=",")
```

Then you can use the most efficient way to find nearest neighbour for each point: KDTree. It's a structure that allows you to find nearest neighbours very fast. So create 2D Tree with your data:

```
from scipy.spatial import KDTree
tree = KDTree(data)
```

KDTree class has a method `query_ball_point(x, r[, p, eps])`    that find all points within distance r of point(s) x. So now for each point in dataset find NN in given radius (your buffer radius), and check if number of NN are greather than your threshold, if true, save this point:

```
for point in data:
    if len(tree.query_ball_point(point, radius)) > threshold:
        # add this point to the new layer
```

Now take this layer and create buffers.

I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: having problems installing SciPy (Windows...) but hopefully I'll be able to give this a try. does look far more efficient than my approach!

Comment: Scipy is avilable in QGIS Python console.

Comment: finally got QGis running with SciPy, I didn't choose that package when I installed it. I used this `writeAsVectorFormat(layer, r'c:\QGIS_testing\accidents.csv', "utf-8", None, "CSV", layerOptions='GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ')` to export the file as CSV, this appears to have worked. Unable to open using loadtxt though `IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('U') or filename: 'C:\\QGIS_testing\x07ccidents.csv'`. Filename is different to the input?

Comment: Maybe `'C:\\QGIS_testing\\x07ccidents.csv'` ? Remember that your csv should contains only X,Y values.

Comment: OK the csv file (when viewed in excel) had all the attributes so perhaps I didn't export correctly? I used [this post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93123/save-as-csv-with-coordinates-in-both-qgis-2-2-and-pyqgis?lq=1) for the syntax, is this not correct?

Comment: have set `layerOptions='GEOMETRY=AS_WKT'` but it still exports with all attributes so I'll do some more looking around to see how to export X, Y only

Comment: got it working, thanks. One last thing - do you know what units this would work with? I've looked at [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_ball_point.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_ball_point) but can't find any info. Would it just use whatever the current map units are?